# Is there a way to stop and start triggering mousemove function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is for touch devices. I have a list with scroll in which when I touch on a list element, it will get highlighted and when we remove the finger with out vertical movement, it will go to its details page. But when we swipe(may be more than 9px pixels towards up or down), this highlight should be gone.This means it is a swipe attempt and not a click attempt.

I am using .mousemove() function to achieve this. But the .mousemove() is creating excess CPU usage for the browser. I need to reduce CPU usage. So is there a way to kill the .mousemove() event once the mouse position moves more than 9 px vertically? And if we try to swipe again, this .mousemove() event should trigger again.

Below is my code. Here "mousedownPosY" is the y position of the mouse when we touch the screen. "newMouseupPosY" is the value we get while swiping. If their difference is more than 9px, it will be a swipe attempt and remove the highlight on the list item.

```
$scope.mousemove=function(index,e){
    var newMouseupPosY = e.pageY;
    var mouseDiff = Math.abs(mousedownPosY - newMouseupPosY);
    if ((Math.abs(newMouseupPosY - mousedownPosY)) > 9) {
      //do something
    }
};
```

If any one have a better method than .mousemove() ,Please share.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Touches have a different event than mouse events

Answer (score 0):

For touch devices you can use Javascript touch event like touchstart,touchmove,touchend.

Try below code may be it will helpful for you.

```
var startY = 0,
curY = 0;
window.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart);window.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);



function onTouchStart(event) {
startY = 0;
curY = 0;

startY = event.touches[0].pageY;}

function onTouchMove(event) {
curY = event.touches[0].pageY - startY;

if (Math.abs(curY) > 9) {
    // do something
}}
```